# install root_numpy in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, numpy, installation, root-framework

I'm trying to install the python package root_numpy, but I can't install it through Anaconda prompt

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install root_numpy

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- root_numpy

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/NLeSC/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/NLeSC/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Anaconda (version 1.7.2),
Python 3.7.4,
numpy  1.16.5

I can't install root, too.

Comment: use pip: `pip install --user root_numpy`

Comment: I used pip install --user root_numpy and I faced new error

 "root-config is not in PATH and ROOTSYS is not set. "
    RuntimeError: root-config is not in PATH and ROOTSYS is not set. Is ROOT installed correctly?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.